# Haar_Training_Cascade running continuously for long time and nothing happens

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, haar-classifier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAgpA.png)

```
 opencv_traincascade -data samples -vec samples.vec -bg negative.txt -numPos 8 -numNeg 9 -numStages 2 -w 50 -h 60 -featureType LBP
```

Here I am doing Haar_cascade_training but after created vector file, When I give the code mentioned above it stopped at the Training Stage 1. I left it for more than 6 hours but nothing happened. My positive samples are 8 and Negative samples are 9. 
Please let me where I am doing mistake.
Thank you....

Comment: Im pretty sure this finished on training stage one as your Hit Rate (1) is larger than your minHitRate (0.995)

Comment: Yes, It's stopped at TRAINING STAGE 1: How can I make it.

Comment: What values should I use then?

Answer (score 0):

`opencv_traincascade` can get into an infinite loop looking for negative samples. One thing you can do is give it more negative images, and make sure that they contain backgrounds typically associated with your objects of interest.

Note also, that training a detector for real on a large data set may well take hours or even days. However, given that you only have 8 positive samples, I am sure that this is an infinite loop.

You can also try the [trainCascadeObjectDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox in MATLAB, which never gets into an infinite loop.

Comment: Okay, So I need to add more negative Images, can you tell me what is the ratio of Positive and Negative Images required.
Thank you Dima

Comment: That's hard to tell. You want a lot of negative images, and you want them to be large. `opencv_traincascade` generates negative samples by scanning the negative images. Anything classified as the object of interest is a false positive, and gets added to the list of negative samples.

Comment: Hi Dima, I added another total of 50 negative Images and when the stage 1 started it suddenly stopped and gives an error REQUIRE LEAF FALSE ALARM RATE BRANCH TRAINING TERMINATED.